To find number of pairs of non-orthogonal vectors in a given set
I am quite stuck on this question. Any ideas/hints on how to approach will be helpful.
Q. Let $E$ be an $n$-dimensional inner-product space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $〈\cdot,\cdot〉$ denote the inner product, and let $A=\{v_1,…,v_m\}⊆E$ be a subset of unit vectors satisfying $〈v_i,v_j 〉=-1$ whenever $v_i$ and $v_j$ are not orthogonal. Denote by $r$ the number of pairs $(i,j),i≠j$, such that $〈v_i,v_j 〉≠0$. Which of the following is/are true?
(a) $r$ can take the value $n$ even if $A$ is linearly independent
(b) $r$ must be at most $n$
(c) $r$ must be at most $\frac{n}{2}$
(d) $r≠n$ if $A$ is linearly independent
Few things I know are:
$(1)$ Orthogonal set of vectors is linearly independent
$(2)$ This question seems to have some connection, but not sure how to link with this one.

Hint: an inner product operation satisfies $〈v_i,v_j⟩  = |v_j||v_j| \cos(\angle (v_i,v_j))$. Given your problem assumptions, what can you say about  the relationship between $v_i$ and $v_j$ when $〈v_i,v_j 〉≠0$?

angle between them is $\pi$ radians

So, given a vector $v_i \in E$, how many vectors  $v_j \in E$ can exist which are NOT orthogonal to $v_i$? Is there perhaps a simpler, algebraic way to express the relationship between non-orthogonal $v_i$ and $v_j$?
I usually think of $π$ radians as $180$ degrees.

You can suppose that they are unitary (or zero) for simplicity

Also there is an easy counterexample for (c)

@user3257842 Geometrically it seems that only one vector is not orthogonal to $v_{i}$, which is $-v_{i}$. But not sure how to prove it.

The statement: "two unitary vectors $v_i$, $v_j$, of angle  $180^{\circ}$ obey $v_i = -v_j$"  is simple enough that I don't think it needs proof.  Here is a proof anyway:
Assume $v_i$, $v_j$ two unitary vectors of angle $\pi$ radians. Now consider the vectors $v_i$ and $-v_j$. For any two arbitrary vectors, we have $\angle(v_i,;v_j) + \angle(v_i,;-v_j) =  \pi$ radians. This means that in our case, we get  $\angle(v_i,;-v_j) = \pi - \angle(v_i,;v_j) = 0$. So, $v_i$, $-v_j$ obey $|v_i| = |-v_j|$ and  $\angle(v_i,;-v_j) = 0$. From this we get $v_i = - v_j$.

Knowing that non-orthogonal $v_i, v_j \in E$ obey $v_i = -v_j$  should be enough to solve the problem.  You can look for examples of a set $E$ in $n = 2$ or $n = 3$ dimensional space to get an intuition for the problem.

@user3257842 Thank you.
